# Flow Control Algorithm selection

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to select an algorithm to implement the following scenario in C.

Scenario : Sender will send same sized data packets at random intervals to 
           receiver. Receive can process data slower than the inqueue rate even though sender sends each packet at random interval.

1.How can I avoid sender overrun & process all the data in receiver side
  without missing the data from sender eventhough it is fast ?

2. Which algorithm will be useful for this case (leaky bucket / Circular Queue / any other) ?? Please suggest

Comment: "receive can process data slower than the inqueue rate" and "process all the data in receiver without missing any" are fundamentally incompatible (without an infinite-length buffer).

Comment: What is the data? What's its type? For numerical data, in certain scenarios,  you can use interpolation to make up for lost data (with approximation of course..).